# Сделал карусель

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Я сделал слайдер ? ведь прокрутку я выполнил
Если кликать влево прокрутки сперва нет,  потом появляется почему ?

```js
var prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
var next = document.querySelector('.next');
var img = document.querySelector('.images');
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images li');

var x = 0;

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
  images[x].style.display = 'none';
  x++

   if(x >= images.length){
    x = 0
  }

  images[x].style.display = 'inline-block';

 
});

prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
  images[x].style.display = 'none';
   x--
    if (x <= 0){
       x = images.length - 1
     }
  images[x].style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  }

  .carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 138px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: auto; 
  }

  .carousel img {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    /* по умолчанию inline, в ряде браузеров это даст лишнее пространство вокруг элементов */

    display: block;
  }

  .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
  }

  .arrow:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  .arrow:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .prev {
    left: 7px;
  }

  .next {
    right: 7px;
  }

  .gallery {
    width: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .gallery ul {
    height: 120px;
    width: 9999px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: margin-left 250ms;
    /* remove white-space between inline-block'ed li */
    /* http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block */

    font-size: 0;
  }
  .gallery li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul class="images">
        <li ><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Эм.. Не работает же...

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил только влево не листайте пожалуйста

Comment: Теперь стрелка влево не работает.

Comment: Qwertiy просил же :)

Comment: @Qwertiy скажите как сделать чтобы прокрутка была влево ?

Comment: @Qwertiy  нашел решение

Comment: @Qwertiy вот так нормально ?

Comment: `if (x <= 0)` — Должно быть строго меньше нуля. Элемент[0] же существует) А вместо `x = 9` (где вы просчитались)... можно сделать `x = images.length - 1;`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  теперь норм ?

Comment: @Leks После `x++`... if(x == images.length - 1){  x = 0  } тут должно быть `images.length` без `-1`. Элемент по номеру `images.length - 1` всё еще существует... вот `images[images.length]` уже будет undefined...

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME вроде все работает ...

Comment: @Leks Такие слайдеры полезнее делать, поставив вместо картинки какие-нибудь пронумерованные блоки. Так легче будет ловить ошибки, чем вспоминать, после какой картинки идет следующий и был ли где-то пропуск...Несколько раз пролистал туда-сюда, последняя местами пропадает)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME ясно, пора теперь замахнутся на табы,  Вы главное действующее лицо :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну разве что так... ширина окон "карусели" приведена к `130px` - как у картинок.
В JS добавлена дополнительная переменная, чтобы каждый раз в него записывать нужные пиксели для текущего маргина и задать стиль в завимисоти от него... Больше ничего не трогал.

Ваше `gallery.style.marginLeft = 0 + 200 + 'px';` - не делает ничего... а каждый раз задает просто `margin-left: 200px;` ( 0 + лишний)

```js
var prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
var next = document.querySelector('.next');
var gallery = document.querySelector('.images');
//Чтобы посчитать суммарный маргин, в зависимости от колчества картинок:
var qty = document.querySelectorAll('.images li');

var x = 0;

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* Изначально у картинок нулевой маргин. 
  Кнопка next должна давать им отрицательный -130px каждый раз. Когда дойдет до
  минус (qty.length - 1) * 130 - некуда будет уменьшаться. Поэтому поставлено условие:
  Если дошло до этого - возвращается до = 0, иначе - уменьшается на 130. */
  x = ( x == - (qty.length - 1) * 130) ? 0 : (x - 130);
  gallery.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
});
prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* Та же история, только в сторону возрастания. Когда ноль - уже некуда расти,
  возвращаем на - (qty.length - 1) * 130  */
  x = ( x == 0 ) ? ( - (qty.length - 1) * 130 ) : (x + 130);
  gallery.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: auto; 
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  /* по умолчанию inline, в ряде браузеров это даст лишнее пространство вокруг элементов */

  display: block;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  left: 7px;
}

.next {
  right: 7px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 250ms;
  /* remove white-space between inline-block'ed li */
  /* http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block */

  font-size: 0;
}
.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="images">
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
</div>
```

Comment: крепитесь впереди еще табы :)) а если серьезно спасибо, буду изучать ваш код как правильно надо

Comment: Та страшная штука с `?` называется Тернарный Оператор) http://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse ... общий вид — —  `( условие ) ? ( значение при выполнении ) : ( значение в остальных случаях )`

Comment: (OPTIMUS PRIME == лучший в js) ? true : false;

Comment: А что выберешь ты ? :))

Comment: error: unknown: Unexpected token, expected "," )) P.s. объективно нельзя оценивать, кто "лучший"... Даже если знать все тонкости языка - дальше уже идут в ход опыт, фантазия и мозги)