# Сделать прокрутку в бок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать горизонтальную прокрутку при нажатии на стрелочки и там были бы другие блоки которые можно добавлять самому с какой то информацией .Я новичок в вебе хотелось бы увидеть подобную реализацию больше на `css` если так можно, ну или на `js`

Заранее спасибо :)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На CSS можно, но будет вынос мозга от комбо-селекторов) Легче вникать в JS ))

Comment: А можете продемонстрировать на js,я просто представления не имею как это сделать,очень  хотелось бы увидеть :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Сделал карусель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988967/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) 
вот здесь можно посмотреть пример 
Вот плагин owl-carousel по вашему вопросу https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html